# How to implement authorization for different users accessing different pages?

Tags: asp.net

`<system.web>
         <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
           </forms>
        </authentication>`
 `</system.web>

     <location path="AssignPage.aspx">
           <system.web>
               <authorization>
                   <deny users="?"/>
              </authorization>
          </system.web>
      </location>`

I just want to make some pages accessible to the anonymous user. Only registered users should have access to all the pages. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Why have you tagged classic ASP?

Comment: *?* means anonymous users. you can set *allow* users for specific set of pages. just make sure the order of authorizations. by the way you should put your configuration you tried in your question.

Comment: @PalakBhansali- Should I write this forms tag ? why is this required ? I am not able to access AssignPage.aspx if I write the code this way. How to make it accessible to registered users only ?